# Form not sliding up

Tags: jquery, forms

I have created 2 forms in same page for sliding..

**HTML - first form**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="reg-1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username" maxlength="50">
    <br />
   <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="Full Name" maxlength="100">
     <br />
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="100">
     <br />
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="32">
     <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit" id="submit">
```

**HTML - second form**

```
<form method="post" id="reg-2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country">
     <br />
   <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State">
     <br />
   <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City">
     <br />
   <select id="relationship" name="relationship">
      <option value="0">Relationship Status</option>
      <option value="Single">Single</option>
      <option value="In a relationship">In a relationship</option>
      <option value="Engaged">Engaged</option>
      <option value="Married">Married</option>
   </select>
      <br />
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Register !" >
```

**jQuery**

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#reg-2").hide();
        $("#submit").click(function(e) {
            $("#reg-1").hide("fast");
            $("#reg-2").show("slow");
            //$("#reg-2").slideUp("slow");
            //e.preventDefault();
          });
       //e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Now the problem is that the sliding is not happening at all, but the page refreshes and stays at form 1 only and doesn't slide at all..

If I remove the comment of `e.preventDefault();` then the page slides without validation and if I add the comment, the page stays at 1st form itself and does not `slideUp` and you can see the validation correctly.

So how should I make it slide after the validation ?

Comment: Did you forget to close `</form>` tags? Also you can't use duplicate IDs for elements, like you did with #submit.

Comment: nope, i've done that, its just that i have copied pasted the code which didn't include closing of form tag.. sorry for that, but I did close it..

Answer (score 0):

Using duplicate IDs is the problem.

Replace id with class property instead:

`<input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit" class="submit">`
`$(".submit").click(function(e) {....`

and don't forget to:

`e.preventDefault();`

http://jsfiddle.net/pe3TS/

Comment: Well, you simply can't with your current code. After first form is validated - page will reload resetting JS code. You need a different approach using AJAX.

Comment: You first need to prepare your `index.php` to output validation errors to `json` format. And study http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/